# Pure Javascript: convert a string to NodeList

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, domparser, nodelist

Using pure javascript, I'm trying to convert a string to NodeList and to append each NodeListItem to a container element, useinf forEach.

**The string list has 6 items, but only 3 are appended.** Why?

```
var controlsString = '<button class="{{namespace}}_prev" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(\'prev\');">Slide to prev</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_pause" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].pause(); this.style.display=\'none\'; this.nextElementSibling.style.display=\'initial\';">Pause</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_play" style="display: none;" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].play(); this.style.display=\'none\'; this.previousElementSibling.style.display = \'initial\';">Play</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_next" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(\'next\');">Slide to next</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_shuffle" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].shuffle();">Shuffle</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_slide_to" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(2);">Slide to 2</button>';
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var getNodes = str => new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
var controlsNodes = getNodes(controlsString);
console.log(controlsNodes);
controlsNodes.forEach(function(controlNode, controls_index, listObj){
    console.log(controlNode);
    container.appendChild(controlNode);
});
```

Look at my experiment on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/lorenzodetomasi/kjhac52y/

Thank you.

Comment: many times I met issues with node list, for me most obvious and simple decision - use `for` loop. it happen because node list is iterable, but it is not array.

Answer (score 4):

The key problem is using `forEach` on result of `childNodes` directly. Quoting the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes):

> `Node.childNodes` read-only property returns a **live** `NodeList` of child
>   nodes of the given element [...]

In other words, each time you append a node from `controlsNodes`, you move it from one place in DOM to another, and the corresponding NodeList is rebuilt - but `forEach()` just doesn't care and moves forward to the next index of that NodeList. That's why each even element of the original collection is skipped.

There're several workarounds for that. The most straightforward is to convert dynamic NodeList to static Array - with either [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
[...controlsNodes].forEach(function(controlNode, controls_index, listObj){
    console.log(controlNode);
    container.appendChild(controlNode);
});
```

An alternative approach is biting the bullet - taking into account the dynamic nature of NodeList:

```
while (controlsNodes.length !== 0) {
  container.appendChild(controlsNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why `forEach` does not work on `NodeList`, but you can iterae over all elements when you convert `NodeList` to `Array.from(controlNodes)` or `Array.prototype.forEach.call(controlsNodes, function (controlNode) {...})`.

Please see corrected code below. For more info any examples refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList.

```js
var controlsString = '<button class="{{namespace}}_prev" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(\'prev\');">Slide to prev</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_pause" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].pause(); this.style.display=\'none\'; this.nextElementSibling.style.display=\'initial\';">Pause</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_play" style="display: none;" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].play(); this.style.display=\'none\'; this.previousElementSibling.style.display = \'initial\';">Play</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_next" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(\'next\');">Slide to next</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_shuffle" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].shuffle();">Shuffle</button>'+
                '<button class="{{namespace}}_slide_to" onclick="isotype_sliders[{{index}}].slide_to(2);">Slide to 2</button>';
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var getNodes = str => new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
var controlsNodes = getNodes(controlsString);

Array.from(controlsNodes).forEach(function(controlNode, controls_index, listObj){
    console.log(controlNode);
    container.appendChild(controlNode);
});
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```